# Sending SMTP mail using POCO C++ through http proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, smtp, poco-libraries

I don't have too much experience programming in C++, but I need to build a basic application for sending state emails from a computer using windows or linux, and I've found that POCO C++ suppoorts both platforms, but I have a proxy http provider behind to filter unauthorized connections, so, how could I do it?.

Comment: My suggestion is that you should start writing without caring about proxies, in the hope that POCO can handle it, and if not _then_ start worrying about it. Hopefully if extra code is needed then you could easily integrate the proxy-code into the existing solution. Also, a HTTP proxy for SMTP? Sounds... Unusual!

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, I had implemented the whole solution using direct connection for sending SMTP mails, but I didn't realized how to do it if my client tries to access the internet resources behind a proxy. I'll keep in mind to change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send SMTP e-mail through a HTTP proxy.

But you can make a HTTP connection to a website you control.  And you can write a web-to-email script and put that on your website.  E.g. your script can take a status message as a POST parameter and then send it out as e-mail.

Spammers often try to hack web-to-email scripts to send spam, so please make sure your script has a hard-coded destination e-mail address.  That way the spammer can only send mail to you, not everyone else on the Internet.  Whatever you do, don't pass the destination e-mail address as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

regarding web to email scripts - make sure you strip newlines from anything that ends up in email headers!  (to prevent spammers from injecting headers)